# Can we solve $u=(x^4+y^4)/x,v=\sin x+\cos y$ for $(x,y)$ near $(\pi/2,\pi/2)$?

Tags: analysis, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

> Let $U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon x\neq 0\}$. For each $(x,y)\in U$, let
> $$u(x,y)=\frac{x^4+y^4}{x}\quad\text{ and }\quad v(x,y)=\sin(x)+\cos(y).$$
> Let $f=(u,v)$ on $U$ and $c=(\pi/2, \pi/2).$ Can we solve for $x,y$ in terms of $u,v$ near $c$? Find $\partial x/\partial u$ near $f(c).$

I'm trying to solve this problem. I don't know what the problem means.

First, I can show that a given function has the inverse at a given point c. Is it not enough? Or I have to solve the system of equations with two variables?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Please [don’t use images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem) instead of [typing your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem You are not asked to solve explicitely the system. Only to justify the existence of a unique solution $(x,y)$, for every $(u,v)$ close enough to $f(c)$.

Comment: As for $\partial x/\partial u$ (in terms of $(x,y)$ close to $c$), remember that $J(f^{-1})_{f(x,y)}=(J(f)_{(x,y)})^{-1}$.